# Keep Getting this Exception With readLine()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-io

So I'm trying to write a loop with a BufferedReader that reads the next lines, converts that line into a double, and then adds it to the sum.  This is to continue to the end of the file.

For some reason I keep getting this error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1017)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
```

Here is what I have for code:

```
while(bReader.readLine() != null)
      {
         line = bReader.readLine();
         double num = Double.parseDouble(line);
         sum = sum + num;
         count++;
      }
```

Comment: readLine second call will again ask for input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read a new line inside your while loop, that returns null:

```
while(bReader.readLine() != null)
      {
         line = bReader.readLine(); // read a second line
         double num = Double.parseDouble(line);
         sum = sum + num;
         count++;
      }
```

change to :

```
while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null)
      {
         double num = Double.parseDouble(line);
         sum = sum + num;
         count++;
      }
```

Comment: @VivekSingh Why? `num` is only used inside the loop.

Comment: so for all the iterations it will keep on creating a variable num with datatype  double. thus increasing time and space complexity (if seen at minor levels). Though it won't effect the purpose or output.

Comment: Thats your opinion. I  think a local used variable sould be declared locally.

Comment: @VivekSingh No it won't. Check the bytecode. There is no instruction corresponding to the declaration of `num` regardless of where you put it, and the stack frame required for a method is allocated at the entry to the method. There is no basis for your claims. It is generally considered best practice to declare Java variables in the smallest possible enclosing scope.